# AngularJS 1.6.6 can't update the model value with $setViewValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

## The Problem

Unable to update Model;

Using the set function I can change the `ngModel` value, and through the pipeline function `$parsers`, however the `Del` function uses splice to process the array, but it can not pass the pipeline function and realizes the update model value.

I tried to use `$scope.$apply ()` to execute after `ngModel.$setViewValue ($scope.images)` and still can't be solved.

The version of the angular used is `1.6.6`.

Online code, [online code links](http://embed.plnkr.co/GaFWZdmJBilvbHxpLHPi/), I hope you can help me to see where the problem is in the end.

## View code

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
    <div image-uploads ng-model="files"></div>
    <p style="display: block; color: red">{{files}}</p>
</div>
```

## Javascript code

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('appController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.files = '1,2,3,4';
    });

    app.directive('imageUploads', function () {
    return {
        require: '?^ngModel',
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div class="image-upload-box"><p class="image_upload" ng-repeat="image in images track by $index"><button ng-click="set()">setModel</button><button ng-click="del($index)">{{image}}</button></p></div>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                var images = new Array();
                if (!ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    var values = modelValue.split(",");
                    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                        images.push({
                            'id': values[j]
                        });
                    }
                }
                return images;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                var s = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < viewValue.length; j++) {
                    if (viewValue[j].id != null) {
                        if (j > 0) {
                            s += ",";
                        }
                        s += viewValue[j].id;
                    }
                }
                return s;
            });

            ngModel.$render = function () {
                $scope.images = ngModel.$viewValue;
            };

            $scope.del = function (i) {
                $scope.images.splice(i, 1);
                ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.images);
            };
            $scope.set = function () {
                console.log('set');
                $scope.images = [{id: 5}, {id: 6}, {id: 7}];
                ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.images);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you try`$scope.images = $scope.images.slice(i, 1)`?

Comment: Thanks, But this is not feasible。

Comment: Why is it not feasible?

Comment: I want to delete an element in $scope.images